# Why does separate table perform significantly better than subquery?

Tags: sql, performance, teradata

I was trying to improve performance of a SQL query and tried few combinations.

**Original Query**

```
SELECT ALIAS_A.id1, 
       ALIAS_A.id2, 
       ALIAS_B.columnA, 
       ALIAS_C.columnB, 
       ALIAS_B.columnC 
FROM   db_A.table_A ALIAS_A 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_A.table_B ALIAS_B 
                    ON ALIAS_A.id2 = ALIAS_B.id2 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_B.table_C ALIAS_C 
                    ON ALIAS_B.columnA = ALIAS_C.item_num 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_A.table_D ALIAS_D 
                    ON ALIAS_A.id2 = ALIAS_D.id2 
       INNER JOIN db_C.table_E ALIAS_E 
               ON Cast(ALIAS_A.column_date AS DATE) BETWEEN 
                  ALIAS_E.column_startdate AND ALIAS_E.column_enddate 
WHERE  ALIAS_E.fiscalyear >= 2016 
       AND Cast(ALIAS_A.columnD AS DATE) BETWEEN 
           CURRENT_DATE - 5 AND CURRENT_DATE
```

The above query consumes nearly 400k impactCPU

**Optimized Query 1**

```
SELECT New_sub_table.id1, 
       New_sub_table.id2, 
       ALIAS_B.columnA, 
       ALIAS_C.columnB, 
       ALIAS_B.columnC 
--changed part start--
FROM   ( sel * from db_A.table_A ALIAS_A WHERE Cast(ALIAS_A.columnD AS DATE) BETWEEN 
           CURRENT_DATE - 5 AND CURRENT_DATE ) New_sub_table -- created a subquery 
--changed part end--
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_A.table_B ALIAS_B 
                    ON New_sub_table.id2 = ALIAS_B.id2 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_B.table_C ALIAS_C 
                    ON ALIAS_B.columnA = ALIAS_C.item_num 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_A.table_D ALIAS_D 
                    ON New_sub_table.id2 = ALIAS_D.id2 
       INNER JOIN db_C.table_E ALIAS_E 
               ON Cast(New_sub_table.column_date AS DATE) BETWEEN 
                  ALIAS_E.column_startdate AND ALIAS_E.column_enddate 
WHERE  ALIAS_E.fiscalyear >= 2016
```

I thought to filter the data first and then do the joins. After I checked the performance stats. It was consuming nearly 390k CPU. Not much of a difference.

**Optimized Query 2**

```
SELECT ALIAS_A.id1, 
       ALIAS_A.id2, 
       ALIAS_B.columnA, 
       ALIAS_C.columnB, 
       ALIAS_B.columnC 
--changed part start--
FROM   INTERMEDIATE_DB.INTERMEDIATE_TABLE ALIAS_A --CREATED AN INTERMEDIATE TABLE
--changed part end--
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_A.table_B ALIAS_B 
                    ON ALIAS_A.id2 = ALIAS_B.id2 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_B.table_C ALIAS_C 
                    ON ALIAS_B.columnA = ALIAS_C.item_num 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db_A.table_D ALIAS_D 
                    ON ALIAS_A.id2 = ALIAS_D.id2 
       INNER JOIN db_C.table_E ALIAS_E 
               ON Cast(ALIAS_A.column_date AS DATE) BETWEEN 
                  ALIAS_E.column_startdate AND ALIAS_E.column_enddate 
WHERE  ALIAS_E.fiscalyear >= 2016
```

**MACRO for loading data into intermediate table**

```
INSERT INTO INTERMEDIATE_DB.INTERMEDIATE_TABLE
sel * from db_A.table_A ALIAS_A WHERE Cast(ALIAS_A.columnD AS DATE) BETWEEN 
           CURRENT_DATE - 5 AND CURRENT_DATE
```

So what I did here was. I used an intermediate table instead of subquery. The intermediate table gets loaded via the macro first and then the select query runs. It now consumes only 50k impactCPU (for both Macro and Select query combined).

**My question -**
I am unable to reason why this is happening even though the logic behind both queries is same (or so I think it is). What would be the best practice if this is incorrect way ?

Comment: Add the execution plans and we'll have something to talk about. In the meantime, a wild guess - please add `option(hash)` to the original query and check the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the `Cast(ALIAS_A.columnD AS DATE)`. When you check Explains you will notice the optimizer has *no confidence* for this step, probably greatly overestimating the number of rows returned.

But when you materialize the Select the number of rows is better known and the order of joins changes.

You would probably get the same plan when you Collect Statistics on the `Cast(ALIAS_A.columnD AS DATE)`, run `DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION;` and Explain should show you this as *recommended stats*.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, I'll check explain plans and revert back. Also, any replacement for CAST(ALIAS_A.TIMESTAMP as DATE). It's a datetime format.

Comment: @PirateX: What's the actual datatype? If it's a Timestamp you can avoid the cast using `ALIAS_A.columnD BETWEEN Cast(CURRENT_DATE - 5 AS TIMESTAMP) AND Cast(CURRENT_DATE+1 AS TIESTAMP)`. If it's a Char/Int there's no workaround. The 2nd bad part is the join using between, I don't know about your tables, but it looks like you join to a calendar to return one row per day in range. This could be solved using Teradata's proprietary `EXPAND ON` syntax.

Comment: Yes it is  `TIMESTAMP(6)`. Can you elaborate on `EXPAND ON` ?

Comment: I checked confidence in both sides, they both show no confidence but the table one estimates the number of rows precisely unlike subquery.

Comment: @PirateX: Are there statistics on that column? Did you run the Diagnostics? Due to the different numbers there should be a different order of joins.